# How do you get different random images from the `CIRandomGenerator` filter?

Tags: ios, core-image

It appears to me that the output of `CIFilter(name: "CIRandomGenerator")` is always the same, regardless of whether one references the `outputImage` of an instance multiple times or whether one instantiates a new filter:

```
import CoreImage
let randomFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIRandomGenerator")
let outputImage = randomFilter!.outputImage!.cropped(to: (CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)))
let outputImage2 = randomFilter!.outputImage!.cropped(to: (CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)))
// pause for some amount of time so that it's definitely not 
// instantiating a PRNG with the same timestamp
let rf2 = CIFilter(name: "CIRandomGenerator")
rf2!.outputImage!.cropped(to: (CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)))
```

Leads to:
[image: playground output]

Which, if you examine the pixels, are all the same.

I do not see any kind of `seed` parameter that can be passed in to initialize the pseudo-random number generator properly.

Since the `CIFilter` has infinite extent, I *can* randomly offset the location in the call to `cropped` and that appears to work, but it seems like a hack. Am I missing the proper way to initialize / `getNext` this random filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost put this as a comment, but I feel it's answer worthy.

That actually seems like you've correctly described it to me. Consider - what is a random number generator? Sure it may take a "seed", but ultimately most generators *will* provide a fairly predictable number if ran time and time again. (Provided you don't start adding other things to the equation.)

So the output of `CIRandomGenerator` may be thought of as the same kind of thing. Taken from (0,0) it's "random" out to infinity. But once you've "seeded" things - given an origin other than (0,0) - you've effectively "captured" something most would consider "random".